# Spring Boot + Freemarker master template

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I`m trying to build an app with spring boot and freemarker as template engine. The problem I have is, I want to make a "master template" for all my pages to use. I found out that this is achievable in Freemarker with macros. This is how my indexmaster.ftl looks like:

```
[#macro indexmaster title="defaultTitle"]
<html>
    <head> css stuff </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">[#nested /]</div>
    </body>
</html>
[/#macro]
```

and in the other pages, I use the macro like this:

```
[#import "/WEB-INF/ftl/master/indexmaster.ftl" as layout /]
[@layout.indexmaster title="My title"]
 ...rest of the page
[/@layout.indexmaster]
```

The problem I`m facing is, the freemarker "code" is interpreted as text when I access the page

[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGriH.png)

What am I doing wrong? Is there any extra spring boot configuration needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "<>" instead of "[]" for Freemarker tags.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.. I followed the basic freemarker macro syntax, therefore the problem.

Comment: The macro syntax is the same as the syntax of the other tags. You can use whichever syntax you want, just configure FreeMarker so. Set the `tag_syntax` setting to `auto_detect` or `square_bracket`. The default is `angle_bracket` for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `tag_syntax` configuration setting of FreeMarker to `auto_detect` or `square_bracket`. The default is `angle_bracket` for backward compatibility. Another option is to start the template with `[#ftl]`, which turns on square bracket syntax even if `tag_syntax` is `angle_bracket`.